# Is there a type for a regular expression in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, regex, jsdoc

I have a regular expression stored in a variable like this:

```
const regex = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{1,}$/
```

I would now like to provide a type using JSDoc. VSCode intellisense suggests:

```
@type {{}}
```

which of course it is. But I am wondering if there is a way to be a little bit more precise by calling it something like:

```
@type {regex}
```

I have been searching the docs and I have been googling and stackoverflowing a few times over past week, but I cannot find a way to define a regular expression in JSDoc.

Comment: Try: `@type {RegExp}`. That's the type for regex. But it's not necessary, when you have assigned a regex to to the var (intellisence knows it's a regex then).

Comment: Thank you @Poul Bak. Did you find this in the docs?

Comment: Nope, I just know that you can do: `new RegExp('pattern')` which gives the same result.

Comment: Proof: `/regexp/.constructor === RegExp // true`.

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @johannes You wouldn't look at the JSDoc docs for this, the problem is you're kind of asking the wrong question. You would look to the JavaScript documentation to figure out the type returned by a regex literal, and then use that in JSDoc. JSDoc doesn't have to document the syntax for all of the thousands of built-in object types.